# Making a gemserver forward requests

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gemserver with gems I was developing internally for a larger application. However in development someone else beat me to open source and put a gem with the same name and a higher version on rubygems.

My question is how can I specifically use my gem from my server, in both a Gemfile and a .gemspec without accidentally pulling down his, or locking the version of my gem and relying on caching the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Pull from a Git Repo

Assuming that you are [pulling the Gem from a git repository](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html).

```
gem 'my-gem', :git => 'git://my-git-repo'
```

### Option 2: Pull from a Local Path

If this is not the case, you may be able to use the [`path`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) option.

```
gem 'my-gem', :path => './vendor/my-gem'
```

### Option 3: Use Source and Source Priority

Alternatively, you could rely upon the [`source`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#source) attribute and [`souce-priority`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY). Basically, bundler will look for the gem in whatever sources you specify before it looks at Ruby Gems.

```
source 'https://my-gem-site.biz'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

### Option 4: Change the Effing Name

Really this option makes the most sense. It's relatively easy for you to change the name of your gem and then push it to the RubyGems site so that no one else can take it. RubyGems specifically says that you must use a unique name.

> **Naming your gem is important**. Before you pick a name for your gem, do a quick search on RubyGems.org and GitHub to see if someone else has taken it. **Every published gem must have a unique name.** Be sure to read our naming recommendations when you’ve found a name you like. ~ [RubyGems Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#consistent_naming) (Emphasis Added)

Comment: I was experimenting with Option 3 (my preferred) and found that Source Priority is misleading. It will take the gem from the priority source only if the version matches or is higher than other sources, otherwise bundler selects higher-versioned gems from rubygems.

I will most likely change old projects to use Option1, and new projects to use the renamed gem (Option 4)